# How do i print results to the command line instead of a popup window using PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Below is the sample code from the PySimpleGUI website, and i like the GUI it outputs, but instead of making it do a popup window when hitting submit, i want it to take those values and put them onto the command line and run a command

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('GreenTan')

form = sg.FlexForm('Everything bagel', default_element_size=(40, 1))

column1 = [[sg.Text('Column 1', background_color='#d3dfda',     justification='center', size=(10,1))],
           [sg.Spin(values=('Spin Box 1', '2', '3'), initial_value='Spin Box 1')],
           [sg.Spin(values=('Spin Box 1', '2', '3'), initial_value='Spin Box 2')],
           [sg.Spin(values=('Spin Box 1', '2', '3'), initial_value='Spin Box 3')]]
layout = [
    [sg.Text('All graphic widgets in one form!', size=(30, 1), font=("Helvetica", 25))],
    [sg.Text('Here is some text.... and a place to enter text')],
    [sg.InputText('This is my text')],
    [sg.Checkbox('My first checkbox!'), sg.Checkbox('My second checkbox!',     default=True)],
    [sg.Radio('My first Radio!     ', "RADIO1", default=True), sg.Radio('My second Radio!', "RADIO1")],
    [sg.Multiline(default_text='This is the default Text should you decide not to type anything', size=(35, 3)),
 sg.Multiline(default_text='A second multi-line', size=(35, 3))],
    [sg.InputCombo(('Combobox 1', 'Combobox 2'), size=(20, 3)),
 sg.Slider(range=(1, 100), orientation='h', size=(34, 20), default_value=85)],
    [sg.Listbox(values=('Listbox 1', 'Listbox 2', 'Listbox 3'), size=(30, 3)),
 sg.Slider(range=(1, 100), orientation='v', size=(5, 20), default_value=25),
 sg.Slider(range=(1, 100), orientation='v', size=(5, 20), default_value=75),
 sg.Slider(range=(1, 100), orientation='v', size=(5, 20), default_value=10),
 sg.Column(column1, background_color='#d3dfda')],
    [sg.Text('_'  * 80)],
    [sg.Text('Choose A Folder', size=(35, 1))],
    [sg.Text('Your Folder', size=(15, 1), auto_size_text=False, justification='right'),
 sg.InputText('Default Folder'), sg.FolderBrowse()],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
 ]

button, values = form.Layout(layout).Read()
sg.Popup(button, values)
```

So my question is for the last line sg.Popup... is there something i can type instead that will put those values on the command line.

Obviously in this example its not a command that is created, but i will eventually change things around so that the user input will be turned into a command that i want run on the command line, so at this point i just need to know how to get the desired values onto the command line instead of a popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the PySimpleGUI GitHub at the Demo Programs and you'll find a couple of them that show you how to "launch" a script or EXE.  If you want to see the output of the command in your window, in realtime, then [this demo program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Script_Launcher_Realtime_Output.py) will do it for you.   There is another one as well that launches a command but doesn't do the realtime output to the window.

Here's the program that does realtime output of the executed command to the window:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Demo Program - Realtime output of a shell command in the window
        Shows how you can run a long-running subprocess and have the output
        be displayed in realtime in the window.
"""

def main():
    layout = [  [sg.Text('Enter the command you wish to run')],
                [sg.Input(key='_IN_')],
                [sg.Output(size=(60,15))],
                [sg.Button('Run'), sg.Button('Exit')] ]

    window = sg.Window('Realtime Shell Command Output', layout)

    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.Read()
        # print(event, values)
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
            break
        elif event == 'Run':
            runCommand(cmd=values['_IN_'], window=window)
    window.Close()


def runCommand(cmd, timeout=None, window=None):
    """ run shell command
    @param cmd: command to execute
    @param timeout: timeout for command execution
    @param window: the PySimpleGUI window that the output is going to (needed to do refresh on)
    @return: (return code from command, command output)
    """
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = ''
    for line in p.stdout:
        line = line.decode(errors='replace' if (sys.version_info) < (3, 5) else 'backslashreplace').rstrip()
        output += line
        print(line)
        window.Refresh() if window else None        # yes, a 1-line if, so shoot me

    retval = p.wait(timeout)
    return (retval, output)


main()
```

Comment: Im looking more for using PySimpleGui to create a user entry box, where the user can enter some key information about a mission, and then the out put uses those entry variables and puts it into a command that gets placed and then run on the command line.  I don't want the user to have to type in the full command.

Comment: The example posted shows you all you need to launch a command.  It's up to your application code to build the command line and then call the function to execute it.  I wasn't trying to write your application but rather show you how it's done.  You can copy and paste most of the code and then modify it to use the Elements you want to create a "user entry box" that builds your command line.

Comment: Here is some code that someone posted that does what you're looking for.... it collected up some variables from the GUI, then builds a command string, then executes that command string:  https://pastebin.com/b0wVgYj9

Comment: Ok great this is getting me where i want to be.  Two questions, 1 is there a website that just talks about all of the routines that PySImpleGUI can do and how to use them?  And 2, is there a routine in PySImpleGUI, where you can input a text or choose from previous entries?

Comment: Here is the docs: http://www.PySimpleGUI.org.  The GitHub, where you can post Issues to get questions answered is http://www.PySimpleGUI.com.  There is extensive documentation.

Comment: Using this structure in my script is generating the following `error [Errno 32] Broken pipe` and it's crashing my GUI. Any suggestions on how I can avoid this issue?

Comment: Open an Issue on the project's GitHub for support.